# Study design using multinomial vs logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, feature-selection, multinomial-distribution, lasso, design-based-inference

Suppose that I have a categorical response variable that consists of group 1-3, and I hope to see if predictors can differentiate group 1 vs group 3 (group 2 not included). The response variable is ordered; for example groups are assigned based on blood pressure,heights, etc.

One way is to fit a multinomial logistic regression and interpret the results, but what happens if I erase out group 2 variable and just fit a logistic regression using group 1 and group 3? I think the multinomial model makes sense, but I could not think of any drawbacks of using the binary model. Would the binary model be biased, or is it an incorrect study design?

(One problem I faced when using the multinomial model is that I have tried to do feature selection using LASSO, but the model produces different sets of nonzero coefficients, and that's why I have leaning toward using logistic version. I don't want to compare group 1 vs group 2,3 or group 1,2 vs group 3)

Answer (score 1):

If the three groups are assigned, as you state, by categorising an inherently continuous variable then you are wasting information by doing that especially if you choose the cut-offs in the light of the data.

If you remove the middle group then you are just left with the ones which are more extreme and so easier to predict which seems likely to give you an optimistic view of the performance of your predictors.

Comment: It would be the best if I could get a 'raw'(continuous) variable, but the data was available as a form of ordered categorical only. I agree that I compare the two extremes, but I wonder if this study design is not reasonable/appropriate.